# List files with same u+o permissions using egrep

Tags: grep

I'm trying to list some files that have the same permissions in User field and Others field. Could you tell me which is the most simple command for this?

Ex: `---x--x--x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `stat` command like this:

```
$ stat --printf="%A %n\n" *
---x--x--x file1
---x-wx--x file2
-rw-rw-r-- file3
$ stat --printf="%A %n\n" * | egrep '^.(.{3}).{3}\1'
---x--x--x file1
---x-wx--x file2
$
```

regex `^.(.{3}).{3}\1` ensure chars from 2nd to 4th index(user permissions) are same as that of that other permissions(`\1` back-reference indicate other permissions).

Another way in which you can do it is using octal representation like this:

```
$ stat --printf="%a %n\n" * | egrep '^([0-9]).\1'
111 file1
131 file2
$
```